# Loop through List of urls and pulling off stock available

Tags: excel, vba, scrape

I have 15,000 web pages all in the same format listed in column A, I need to pull of the available stock for each product and paste it into Column H. I have tried multiple solutions that I have found online with no success.

My first URL is : view-source:https://www.coolings.co.uk/shop/products/plants/bedding/all-bedding/osteospermum-mixed-10-5cm-pot.html

The figure I want is nestled here (125):

```
<div class="availability-wrapper">
      <div class="availability in-stock">125 available</div>
  </div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: They are all the same, sorry I should have referenced the other code i have tried to modify with no success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962497/webscrape-loop-on-all-urls-in-column-a/67266821#67266821

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, to get the available stock from the URL you provided. You would have to loop over all the URLs and adjust the code acordingly:

```vb
Sub getStock()
    Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, Ele As Object
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.navigate "https://www.coolings.co.uk/shop/products/plants/bedding/all-bedding/osteospermum-mixed-10-5cm-pot.html"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    
    Set Doc = IE.Document
    Set Ele = Doc.getElementsByClassName("availability in-stock")
    
    Debug.Print Ele(0).innerText
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing: Set Doc = Nothing: Set Ele = Nothing
End Sub
```